# How to match the first word after a specific expressions with regex?

Tags: swift, regex

My code below match the first word after one expression "let" :

```
(?<=\blet\s)(\w+)
```

What I need is to match the first word after a specific expressions, "let", "var", "func"

Input text:

```swift
let name: String
var age: Int
func foo() {
//...
```

Expected:

```
name
age
foo
```

Here is an image for clarity:
[image]

Comment: Use `(?:let|var|func)\s+(\w+)` and grab 1st capture group

Comment: Also try: [`\b(?:let|var|func)\s\K(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/As2J18/1), NOTE: `\K` works not for any regex flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Since some regex flavors do not allow using groups inside lookbehinds and alternatives of different length, it is safe to use a non-capturing group with the lookbehind as alternatives:

```
(?:(?<=\blet\s)|(?<=\bvar\s)|(?<=\bfunc\s))\w+
```

Here, `(?:...|...|...)` is a non-capturing group matching one of the three alternatives: `(?<=\blet\s)`, `(?<=\bvar\s)` and `(?<=\bfunc\s)`.

Comment: This is a really nice trick. Using an alternation of lookbeinds instead of a lookbehind of alternation, to bypass the "variable length lookbehind" problem.

Comment: If variable-length lookbehinds are supported:  `(?<=\b(?:let|var|func)\s)\w+`